# How to replace regex string matches (one by one) in file2 by the same matches from the similar file1 in Python?

Tags: python, regex, replace, find, copy

I need to copy regex matches from one structured .txt file and paste it into another similar .txt file, so that the found regex matches from file_1 will replace the same matches in file_2, one by one, by file_1 matches?

Example text files with the strings for replacement:

```
#TXT file 1:

randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_new_STRING_Arandomtext_
randomtext_randomtext_new_STRING_Brandomtext_randomtext_randomtext_
randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_
new_STRING_Crandomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_

#TXT file 2 (the exact same structure, but a little different strings values):

randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_old_STRING_Arandomtext_
randomtext_randomtext_old_STRING_Brandomtext_randomtext_randomtext
_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_
old_STRING_Crandomtext_randomtext_randomtext_randomtext_
```

How do I copy strings found by using regex: new_STRING_A, new_STRING_B and new_STRING_C from file_1.txt into file_2.txt in place for the same regex matches: old_STRING_A, old_STRING_B, old_STRING_C, so that the new strings from file_1 will replace old strings from file_2?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regex, only string comparaison sufices

```
with open('file_1.txt') as f1 : 
  content = f1.readlines() 
  content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

with open('file_2.txt') as f2 : 
  content2 = f2.readlines() 
  content2 = [x.strip() for x in content] 

for line in content : 
  for line2 in content2 : 
      if 'old_STRING_A' in line2 and 'old_STRING_A' in line1 :
       line2 = line1 
      elif 'old_STRING_B' in line2 and 'old_STRING_B' in line1 :
       line2 = line1 
      elif 'old_STRING_C' in line2 and 'old_STRING_C' in line1 :
       line2 = line1 

with open('file_2.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for line in content2 : 
      f2.write(line+'\n')
```

for using regex

```
import re 

with open('file_1.txt') as f1 : 
  content = f1.readlines() 
  content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

with open('file_2.txt') as f2 : 
  content2 = f2.readlines() 
  content2 = [x.strip() for x in content] 

for line in content : 
  for line2 in content2 : 
      re.sub(r'[^]?old_STRING_A[^]?','new_STRING_A',line)

with open('file_2.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for line in content2 : 
      f2.write(line+'\n')
```

Comment: Thank you Nassim, but let's suppose this was just an example and the actual files would be much more complex, therefore they would require regex to find all the needed strings in file_1 and then replace the similar ones in file_2, one by one. What would the code look like with regex findall method (or maybe other) in such a case?

Comment: are all the strings the same, i mean 123-new_STRING_A-45 equivalent in file_2 is always 123-old_STRING_A-45 and not like 1-old_STRING_A2345

Comment: Thank you Nassim for following up. No, they are not the same. It's more like <ID="336298sdf76sd5f7ds5f8" in file_1 and <ID="f7s5Z8sdf76sd5f7djZui"
 in the file_2. That's why I think I would have to use regex here.

Comment: in this example you just showed me,could you please show me where is new_STRING_A in <ID="336298sdf76sd5f7ds5f8"  and old_STRING_A in  <ID="f7s5Z8sdf76sd5f7djZui ?

Comment: Let's say the new strings (i.e. <ID="336298sdf76sd5f7ds5f8") are in file_1, and the old ones (i.e. <ID="f7s5Z8sdf76sd5f7djZui") are in file_2.

new_String_A and old_String_A are the placeholders for i.e. <ID="0xX00x0X00xX00x" strings type.

Comment: did you consider using the_string.replace(old_string,new_string) ? I'm really sorry i didn't understand you well, if you want to use regex, i'll update my answer to show you how they are used

Comment: I didn't consider using string.replace, because I don't know all the strings, there are 100 or more such strings and I have to first find them using regex. In my example "new_String_A" or "old_String_A" are just placeholders for what I am really dealing with in the actual files, that are too long to paste them here.

If you could help me with using regex for my example, that would be superb, because then I could try to apply it to the real file that has plenty of strings to be replaced from one file to another (using regex). Thank you!

Comment: Let's say the file_1 has multiple strings like this: <ID="f7s5Z8sdf76sd5f7djZui", and file_2 also has multiple such strings. What I want to do is to find such strings (using regex) and then copy them from file_1 onto file_2, to just replace the ID strings (i.e. <ID="f7s5Z8sdf76sd5f7djZui") from file_2 by the similar strings from file_1. Do you get it, my friend?

Comment: Still looking for help. My goal is to: 
   1. Search for strings in File 1 using Regex
    2. Search for strings in File 2 using the same Regex
    3. Replace found matches from File 1 for found matches in File 2

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this and it doesn't work. My goal is to:

1. Search for strings in File 1 using Regex
2. Search for strings in File 2 using the same Regex
3. Replace found matches from File 1 for found matches in File 2

```
file1 = r'C:\Users\file_1.txt'
file2 = r'C:\Users\file_2.txt'


with open(file2) as f1 : 
 content = f1.readlines() 
 content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

with open(file1) as f2 : 
 content2 = f2.readlines() 
 content2 = [x.strip() for x in content] 

for line in content : 
 for line2 in content2 : 
     re.sub(r'[^]?old_STRING_A[^]?',r'[^]?new_STRING_A[^]?',line)

with open(file1, 'w') as f2:
   for line in content2 : 
     f2.write(line+'\n')
```